# required init in Swift - can't get this working

Tags: swift, initialization, sprite-kit

I have problem with my game. I trying to override init and I don't get any errors when compile, but code after "override init" is never excecuted. Only part with "required init" is work. What i am doing wrong?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)         // nie wiem o co tu chodzi, ale tak przynajmniej dziala

}

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    gracz = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "paletka")
    gracz.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, gracz.size.height/2+20)

    self.addChild(gracz)

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) //brak grawitacji dla paletki
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self //do wykrywania zderzen
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean "code after `override init` is never excecuted"? It is not going to be executed by itself; it will only be executed if you say `GameScene(size:someSize)`. Do you ever say that? You certainly do not say it in any of the code you are showing here so far. Why _should_ it be executed?

Comment: I have GameScene(size:someSize) in other file, but it only see GameScene(NSCoder), and say it doesn't find size member in GameScene.

Comment: can you use a breakpoint to make sure the code is never being executed?  click on the bar on the left side

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Why do you want to override `init`?

Comment: @hamobi I make sure about this using console printline.

Comment: @0x141E I want to override it, to init this class from other class using: "GameScene(size: self.size)". But other file see only "GameScene(coder)"

Comment: You can add your initialization code to `didMoveToView` and create your scene with the built-in `init(size:CGSize)` method.